# Hide leaflet features out of specified area

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to hide some leaflet features outside of a defined area.

I have a leaflet map displaying rivers as features on a RiverLayer and a circleLayer used to draw an area around the current center of the map.

Each river is separated in multiple parts inside my database and I retrieve only the parts intersecting with my current circle area.

The result look like this:
[image: exampleRivers]

The rivers are showing outside the area, because I selected the parts intersecting with it.
I could select in my database all the parts within the area but I would lose the parts that are not entirely inside the area.

Calculating the intersection point for each part concerned in order to adjust the coordinates would be a solution but a complex one.

In fact, I would prefer to simply hide these overflows on the client side but I can't find a solution.

Is there a possibility with leaflet to do something like this?

Thanks for you time

Comment: I would definitely look at turf to crop data before displaying it https://turfjs.org/

Comment: Yeah i saw turf and it could be a solution. But it seems I would need to do a lot of calculations myself (for a river part, I would need to filter each geojson point to verify the distance, remove the points outside the area, calculate the intersection point between my circle and my river part, and add this intersection point to the start or end of the river part depending on the distance from each...). Or maybe there is an existing function in Turf but I didn't found it.

Comment: indeed it would be easy with a square or rectangle with the clip function https://turfjs.org/docs/#bboxClip . with point and polygon pointsWithin is doing the job https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon

Comment: Pls share a online demo f.e. on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is a basic demo of my problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/out-of-circle-leaflet-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using turfJS using the booleanWithin and lineSplit functions.
[image]

I did the example on a simple basic HTML and Vanilla JS. I added another linestring on the "river" to simulate an outside the circle river

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([43.63458105967136, 1.1613321304321291], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(mymap);

var center = [43.63458105967136, 1.1613321304321291];
var radius = 1500;

// L.circle(center, radius, {
//     color: '#ff4081', fillColor: '#ff4081', fillOpacity: 0.5
// }).addTo(mymap);

var riverGeoJSON = [
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "coordinates": [[1.159444487444759, 43.633815447205706], [1.160243520516838, 43.634633600388156], [1.160731009187281, 43.6350432633719], [1.161774921971743, 43.63541373375439], [1.162079879908259, 43.63564209781788], [1.162320030539753, 43.635959368371424], [1.162373764624914, 43.636409391647234], [1.161800286153361, 43.637212422659154], [1.160910734693605, 43.63832601539633], [1.160651867030764, 43.63886255455486], [1.160332394101095, 43.639317964879666], [1.159189872203288, 43.640743176542664], [1.158053840843969, 43.641810274789506], [1.156922548158863, 43.642651534145514], [1.155851918485514, 43.64349381183714], [1.155156982509935, 43.644214650781954], [1.15326441791592, 43.64594659208024], [1.152374775964331, 43.6470151231795], [1.151428904349222, 43.64790448439313], [1.151107886218696, 43.64840394819371]], "type": "LineString" } },
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "coordinates": [[1.156570800342349, 43.632121495293006], [1.158291185472127, 43.63272397754135], [1.158901458643683, 43.633090727638866], [1.159444487444759, 43.633815447205706]], "type": "LineString" } },
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "coordinates": [[1.168152938761366, 43.62917262321181], [1.167467920251437, 43.62939958202886], [1.166101976396903, 43.62960874939632], [1.164673843635074, 43.629863651007135], [1.163738326615552, 43.63021236020524], [1.163236303364402, 43.630566588076604], [1.162728104605807, 43.63119071739829], [1.161282685092185, 43.632253508072225], [1.160336935333006, 43.633151033736986], [1.159444487444759, 43.633815447205706]], "type": "LineString" } },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    1.0526275634765625,
                    43.550289946081115
                ],
                [
                    1.07940673828125,
                    43.63334186269
                ],
                [
                    1.0764884948730469,
                    43.6336524704596
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
];
// L.geoJSON(riverGeoJSON, {}).addTo(mymap);

var centerGeoJSON = [center[1], center[0]];
var radiusGeoJSON = radius / 1000;
var options = { steps: 50, units: 'kilometers' };
var circleGeoJSON = turf.circle(centerGeoJSON, radiusGeoJSON, options);

L.geoJSON(circleGeoJSON, {}).addTo(mymap);

var riverClipped = {}

for (let index = 0; index < riverGeoJSON.length; index++) {
    const feature = riverGeoJSON[index];
    var within = turf.booleanWithin(feature, circleGeoJSON);
    console.log({ within });
    var split = turf.lineSplit(feature, circleGeoJSON);
    console.log({ split });
    if (within && split.features.length === 0) {
        L.geoJSON(feature, {}).addTo(mymap);
    } else {
        L.geoJSON(split.features[0], {}).addTo(mymap);
    }


}
```

Circle is calculated with turfJS to have a valid GeoJSON feature. This feature is then used as a splitter.

When line is completely inside the circle, the `within` function returns `true`, the split function doesn't return a split feature.

When line is completely outside the circle, the `within` function is `false` and the split function doesn't return a split feature.

When the line intersect the circle, the `within` function returns `false`, and the first feature from the split feature collection is the one inside the circle.

Complete source code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsamaya/6sc58m7u/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just a precision, its not exactly true when you say "the first feature from the split feature collection is the one inside the circle.". It depends on the coordinates of the line string and the coordinates of the circle. In some cases, the first feature returned is the one outside the circle. I simply used the booleanPointInPolygon (https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon) method to determine if the first feature was the one, and take the second feature if this was not the case and everything is good now.